# Git pulling without root access

Tags: git, chmod, chown, pull

On a Ubuntu Server 10.10 box, I seem to require root access to use git pull (in my `/var/www` directory). `error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied`.

I have tried chmodding 0777 `/var/www` and `/var/www/.git`, and chowning both of these to my account, to no avail.

Answer (score 6):

For whatever reason, you do not have access to the local file .git/FETCH_HEAD .

The solution to this is to run `chown -R youruser .git/`

Once you run this, you should be able to run it without the sudo.

Answer (score 4):

The error message is *not* about `/var/www` or `/var/www/.git`. It is about `/var/www/.git/FETCH_HEAD`, which you need write permissions on.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need permissions on the whole directory and all the files to be able to pull.